# How to select the information from the table?

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a table like:

```
user_id | log_id | action_id
############################
191     | 11111  | 1
191     | 11111  | 2
191     | 11111  | 3
191     | 11111  | 999
191     | 22222  | 4
191     | 22222  | 5
191     | 22222  | 6
191     | 33333  | 7
191     | 33333  | 8
191     | 33333  | 9
191     | 33333  | 999
191     | 44444  | 10
191     | 44444  | 11
191     | 44444  | 12
......
......
......
```

I want a result like this, action_id = 999 and all other rows with the same log_id:

```
user_id | log_id | action_id
############################
191     | 11111  | 1
191     | 11111  | 2
191     | 11111  | 3
191     | 11111  | 999
191     | 33333  | 7
191     | 33333  | 8
191     | 33333  | 9
191     | 33333  | 999
......
......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
SELECT a.* FROM table as a
join ( SELECT log_id FROM table WHERE action_id = 999 ) b on a.log_id=b.log_id
```

Answer (score 1):

A sub-select should do it,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE log_id IN ( SELECT log_id FROM table WHERE action_id = 999);
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE log_id IN (SELECT log_id FROM table_name WHERE action_id = 999)